# How to implement Restful Webservice using C++

Tags: c++, web-services, http, rest

Are there any helpful c++ libraries which can support me, implementing a simple REST webservice?
I am not searching for a bloated webservice framework like [c++ REST SDK](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/), or something like that. I already have a HTTP server running which can handle HTTP calls. (especially the [HTTP server](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html) from the poco libraries).
I guess it should be not too hard to implement a Restful webservice interface around that. 
But my question is, do i have to implement it on my own (how would you implement it?) or can I still make use of some libraries? So I am searchin for a library that can actually help me processing rest requests.

kind regards

Comment: maybe those links will help you:
https://code.google.com/p/staff/
https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp
https://github.com/konteck/wpp

Comment: thank you i will look into the last two links. but actually i already know `staff` and it will come with an own http web server right? that's not what i need, because i'm already running a http server. Im looking for stuff necessary to proccess rest requests.